# System.Net.Http.HttpClient in [Universal Windows Platform] not working properly

Tags: c#, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I wrote simple method for getting data from (online) REST Service:

```
    public async Task<Object> GetTask()
    {
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://111.111.111.111:8080/");
                HttpResponseMessage result = await client.GetAsync("ABC/CDE/getsomeinfo");
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Deserialize
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error" + ex);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Whenever i run this on UWP i'm getting catch exception:

The text associated with this error code could not be found.

A connection with the server could not be established

HResult 2147012867

Im trying to connect my client with restapi in internal network. In forms same code is working properly.

Comment: Did you give your app the capability to access the local network? (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations , the `privateNetworkClientServer` cap). Can you do a raw TCP socket connection to the target IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
HttpResponseMessage response;

public async Task<string> webserviceResponse(string HttpMethod)
{      
    // check internet connection is available or not   

    if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() == true)
    {
       // CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(2000); // 2 seconds
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        MultipartFormDataContent mfdc = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        mfdc.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");
        string GenrateUrl = "your url";

        if (HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            response = await client.PostAsync(GenrateUrl, mfdc);

        }
        else if (HttpMethod == "PUT")
        {
            response = await client.PutAsync(GenrateUrl, mfdc);
        }
        else if (HttpMethod == "GET")
        {
            response = await client.GetAsync(GenrateUrl);
        }
        var respon = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        string convert_response = respon.ToString();
        return convert_response;
    }
    else
    {
        return "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: I set internet capability in Package.appxmanifest and its work, thx

Comment: set to what capability?